# Why do I have to pay for something that I already bought?

Tags: music

ALL I want to do is have access to my itunes library (that I created from my PC) on my iphone.  WHY do I have to pay AGAIN to Apple Music for music that I've already paid for in itunes?  If I sign up for the free Apple Music trial will my already purchased itunes download AND still be available on my iPhone after I unsubscribe?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to subscribe to Apple Music if you only want to sync your iTunes library from your computer to your iPhone. Apple has described the details in [Sync your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch with iTunes on your computer using USB](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201253). In a nutshell

- Install iTunes on your Mac or PC
- Import your audio library into iTunes
- Connect your iPhone to your computer using the included USB cable. It appears as an icon in the upper-left corner of the iTunes window
- Click on the device icon
- Select syncing options for the various content types
- Click on "Apply" at the bottom right to start syncing (may take a while for the first sync)

Comment: You also need to ensure that Apple Music hasn't been turned on automatically by Apple. If it has you will need to switch it off for all your devices in Settings.